# Check if Docker Container is running on Azure VM via Powershell

Tags: azure, docker, powershell, azure-functions, virtual-machine

I am trying to create a PowerShell Script inside a Function App that checks if a Docker Container is running on an Azure VM. So far I have managed to check wether the VM is running with the following script:

```
$provisioningState = (Get-AzVM -resourcegroupname $rsgName -name $vmName -Status).Statuses[1].Code
$condition = ($provisioningState -eq "PowerState/running")
```

However, I am not able to check the Docker status. How can I check from a Function App whether Docker is running on the VM using PowerShell?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to run the command on the VM to check docker then you could use the Run Command and `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand`.

As this requires the script to be local to where the command is being run you may have to store the script inside the function app or write a wrapper function/module to make use of it.

Docs on that are here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#powershell